# Catch Exception of PictureMask Validation of wwDBedit control on exit

Tags: delphi, exception, mask

I use delphi in my company's project.
I am using infopower's control and i've got a **DBedit** that in which have set up a picturemask. In case of an wrong type value insertion, on exiting of the control, i want to catch the exception in order to alter the exception message. 
My problem is that i cannot understand when picturemask validation happens. I try to put **Try/Except** block on the **OnExit** event but it isn't getting cached and is firing with the default message.

I have seen in the original code of the control that the exception comes inside of a **CMExit** procedure that is private and i cannot override it or understand which event triggers it.

I am asking how can i catch that message in my code.

Comment: Finally remove that picturemask and made my custom validation. But the answer of @bummi is more close in what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an interposer class to your form and handle the exception within the message CM_EXIT.

```
type
  TwwDBEdit= class (wwdbedit.TwwDBEdit)
    procedure CMExit(var Message: TCMExit); message CM_EXIT;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    wwDBEdit1: TwwDBEdit; 
  //..... other declarations here
implementation

{$R *.dfm}
{ wwDBEdit1 }

procedure TwwDBEdit.CMExit(var Message: TCMExit);
begin    
  try
    inherited; // call the inherited handler within try
  except
    Showmessage('Your Code'); // and handle it in except
  end;

end;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try
  // Code

except
  on E : Exception do begin
    if E.Message = 'Type here the originally exception text' then begin
      // Code
    end;
```